# 96-bit output hash function

Tags: cryptography, rfid

I am trying to encrypt the contents of an EPC Gen 2 RFID tag, but most of the common hashing functions take up significantly more space than I have available (96 bits in data bank). Is there an existing library or a good way to map to this space?

Comment: Make sure you understand the security implications of what you're wanting before you go down this path.

Comment: Do you want to encrypt or do you want to hash? As Reid is trying to suggest, 96 bit is rather short for a secure hash.

Comment: Also note that hashing != encryption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pick any hash algorithm with an output of greater than 96 bits, and use just 96 bits of the result. Just be sure you're consistent and, say, always take the least signficiant 96 bits.

Comment: The common method in cryptography is to take the leftmost bits, which would be the "most significant" bits when considering big endian numbers (which is used as common endianness most of the time). Of course, with a hash not usually being a number, talking about taking the least significant is moot.

Comment: Indeed, I could have said "leftmost" or "rightmost", but consistency is the point there. Any reasonable hash algorithm has uniform entropy in all bits of its output.

Comment: That's true, but every hash function and every MAC and every KDF I know uses the leftmost bytes, so I would strongly recommend keeping to that ad-hoc standard.

Comment: @owlstead Well there is HOTP/TOTP which uses a random position. Some people like unnecessary complexity...

Comment: @CodesInChaos Sheesh. How to show you don't understand cryptography. I'm in a constant fight against complexity in protocols, I think your example helps to show that you *should* keep to standards, even ad-hoc ones.